# Fixed div stretches wider than screen on mobile. Why?

Tags: html, css

In this simplified HTML, I have a fixed div that is meant to be the exact width of the window. But there is also a very long word in the content above the div that messes up the layout.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1">
    <style>
      div {
        position: fixed;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body><p>Veryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryverylongword</p>
    <div><b>0%</b><b>25%</b><b>50%</b><b>75%</b><b>100%</b></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

It looks as if the long word causes the "viewport" to stretch to be wider than the window, so the div (fixed to the viewport) ends up being wider than the window.

Now this only happens on mobile devices, even using Chrome Dev Tools. In Desktop mode, all is fine:

[image: Desktop mode: GU!]

But change to Mobile and the fixed div stretches:

[image: Mobile mode: NG!]

So two questions:

1. How can I prevent the div from stretching wider than the window?
2. What is Chrome Dev Tools doing differently when I switch to Mobile view?

Comment: My Chrome keeps both divs at exactly the viewport width no matter how small I scale them, regardless of what settings I have in the responsive mode. I don't even see "Desktop" in the drop-down; what version/OS are you on?

To answer your question though, I would try `max-width: 100vw;`

Comment: @Timofey Chrome 67.0.3396.99 on Mac OS. You know, I think `width:100vw` might help (though it may not solve the problem completely).

Comment: I see what you mean. I posted an answer cause I thought it fixed it but even with that setting the <p> is sometimes wider than the viewport... I'll post something if I figure it out. Very intrigued :) Btw I've become able to reproduce the problem just by making changes and spamming refresh until something broke, but it's definitely not acting like a standard or specified behavior

Answer (score 2):

1) I've managed to fix all the issues I can create with your code by:

```
p {
  max-width: 100vw;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

2) Chrome does very strange things with the width of that div as I mess with the css and refresh the page. It does not render at all consistently even with the same css. In fact, I have two tabs open that show the page differently from the same code in the same file, even while refreshing. I think the behavior of a div when smaller than the viewport may be unspecified, and you must use something like my solution to tell Chrome what to do.

Comment: Yeah, setting `overflow:hidden` fixes the problem, but the downside is that the overflow is hidden! (i.e. you can't see all the long word)

Comment: Setting `overflow:hidden` on the div at least keeps it to the right size, but it still moves when you scroll sideways. I just want to make the behaviour on mobile the same as it is on desktop.

Answer (score -1):

this problem is caused by `justify-content: space-between`. You dont actually set a width, and different things add different amounts of spacing.

If you were to set a width for the div like this: `width: 300px`, the width wouldn't change on mobile or pc.

Comment: No, the problem still occurs even if there is no styling on the div at all. The `display` and `justify-content` are only there to make it easier to see the problem.

Comment: So I'm assuming this isnt the real div, and that this is just an example. Can you show me the real div's css (or describe it to me)? Thanks! Pls no downvote ty

Comment: Yes, this is just an example. No point posting more complex code when this simple example exhibits the problem. If you prefer, just remove the `display` and `justify-content` styles. The only important styles are `display`, `left` and `right`.

Comment: it could be due to the phones horizontal and vertical displays, i just took my phone and the width seems to be about 60% of the height, which is how much your div is strecthed

Comment: No, the `div` is stretched to the width of the long word in the `p` above the `div`. It's the long word that causes the problem by stretching (apparently) the viewport, but only on mobile view.